# jQuery Slider previous button doesn't work as expected

Tags: jquery, html, slider

i have this problem with the previous button of my jQuery slider 
when i click next button it works fine but the previous button doesn't get the previous element and i don't know why !! this is my Code

HTML :

```
<div class="sliderContent">

<figure>Img here</figure>
<h3>Title here!</h3>

</div> 

<div class="sliderContent">

<figure>Img here</figure>
<h3>Title here!</h3>

</div>
<div class="sliderContent">

<figure>Img here</figure>
<h3>Title here!</h3>

</div>
<div class="sliderContent">

<figure>Img here</figure>
<h3>Title here!</h3>

</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <div class="prev"></div>  
  <div class="next"></div>
```

jQuery :

```
$(function(){


sliderInt= 0;
sliderNext = 1;

count = $(".sliderContent").length -1 ;




$(".sliderContent h3").hide().fadeIn(1200);

$(".sliderContent").eq(sliderInt).fadeIn(500);





$(".prev").click(function(){



    $(".sliderContent").fadeOut(500);
    $(".sliderContent").eq(sliderNext).fadeIn(500);


sliderNext = sliderNext -1 ;

    if(sliderNext < 0) {

              sliderNext = count ;

    }




});  });
```

i deleted the code of next button just to check if the problem was from this one

Comment: can fiddle it please

Comment: For example i have 5 divs i want to slide them .. so count = 5 -1 =4 .. I did that because .eq() starts from 0 not from 1 .. when i click next button the slider works fine .. but previous button .. it gets an unwanted div ( or image) .. here is the code so where is my mistake ?? Thank you ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify with this:

The problem is you are fading in the next  slide while clicking previous button you should fade the previous  slide

```
    $(".prev").click(function(){
    sliderNext = count;

    $(".sliderContent").fadeOut(500);
    $(".sliderContent").eq(sliderNext).fadeIn(500);


    sliderNext = sliderNext -1 ;


    if(sliderNext <= 0) {
                  sliderNext = count ;
        }
});
```